# Varias ordenações com ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, classificação, comparação, arraylist

Estou com uma duvida.
Quero ordenar o ArrayList pessoa de diferentes formas.

```
<%@ page import= "java.util.*"%>

<%! 
public class Pessoa implements Comparable<Pessoa> {  
    String Nome;  
    Integer numero; 

    public  Lista(String n,int m){  
        this.Nome = n;  
        this.numero = m;  
    }  

    public String getNome(){
        return Nome;
    }  
    public void SetNome(String Nome){
        this.Nome = Nome;
    }   
    public Integer getArea(){
        return numero;
    }     
    public void SetArea(int numero){
        this.numero = numero;
    }  
    public String toString(){  
        return this.Nome+" "+this.numero;
    }

    // Para ordenar por nome 
    private static void ordenaPorNome(List<Pessoa> lista) {
    Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Lista o1, Lista o2) {
            return o1.getNome().compareTo(o2.getNome());
        }
    });
    }
    // Para ordenar por numeros
    private static void ordenaPorNumero(List<Pessoa> lista) {
    Collections.sort(lista, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Lista o1, Lista o2) {
            return o1.getArea().compareTo(o2.getArea());
        }
    });
    }       

}

%>


<%

    List<Pessoa> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();  
    Lista t1,t2,t3; 
    t1 = new Lista("a",3);  
    t2 = new Lista("b",2);  
    t3 = new Lista("c",1); 

    lista.add(t1);  
    lista.add(t2);  
    lista.add(t3);

    //como chamar o metodo de ordenação aqui ?
    ordenaPorNome(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);

    //como chamar o metodo de ordenação aqui ?
    ordenaPorNumero(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);

%>
```

Estou usando JSP, e fica tudo no mesmo arquivo.

Ai posteriormente, vai ter uma opção para o usuário escolher a forma de ordenar, e também adicionar mais atributos na class pessoa para serem ordenados.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve usar a interface [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). E por sua vez invocar o método [Collection.sort(List, Comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-);

Por exemplo

```
Collection.sort(list, new Comparator<Pessoa>() {
    public int compare(Pessoa p1, Pessoa p2) {
        return  p1.numero.compareTo(p2.numero);
    }
});
```

Para cada atributo você deverá criar o `Comparator`. Em Java 8 você pode usar expressão Lambda. Se precisar de exemplos nos avise.

Comment: Eu não poderia colocar esse seu exemplo dentro de um método, e depois chamar o método fora da class, para ordenar de acordo com os parâmetros que eu receber ?

Comment: Sim, você pode implementar dessa forma. Eu faria algo assim: 1. Criaria todos os prováveis Comparators. 2. Criaria um Map, com todos eles. 3. Com a chave, buscaria o comparator no map. Qualquer fala ai. Olhando seu código, seria legal tirar de dentro de páginas jsp.

Answer (score 1):

**Sugestão**:
Altere os métodos de  ordenação para `public` ao invés de `private`, assim você poderá utilizar em qualquer outro lugar.

Para realizar a a chamada, os métodos estão estáticos e estão dentro de Pessoa certo?

Então ficaria assim:

```
    Pessoa.ordenaPorNome(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);


   Pessoa.ordenaPorNumero(lista);
    System.out.println(lista);
```