# Ordenar objetos de acordo ao atributo nome usando Collections.sort() ou reverse()

Tags: java

Como ordenar os objetos através do atributo nome? Estou implementando a interface Comparator.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo.

Vamos aos códigos:

**arquivo: Pessoa.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  

public abstract class Pessoa {  
    protected String nome;  
    protected int telefone;  
    protected int matricula;  
    private static int contadorMatricula;  

    private static int atribuirMatricula() {  
        Pessoa.contadorMatricula++;  
        return Pessoa.contadorMatricula;  
    }  

}
```

**arquivo: PessoaFisica.java**

```
public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa {  
    protected int cpf;  

    public PessoaFisica(String nome, int telefone, int cpf) {  
        this.nome=nome;  
        this.telefone=telefone;  
        this.cpf=cpf;  
    }  

}
```

**arquivo do main: Main.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Collections;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.Comparator;  

public class Main implements Comparator<PessoaFisica> {  

    @Override  
    public int compare(PessoaFisica pessoa1, PessoaFisica pessoa2) {  
        return pessoa1.nome.compareTo(pessoa2.nome);  
        }  

    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        List pessoasFisicas = new ArrayList<>();  

        PessoaFisica pessoa1=new PessoaFisica("André Nascimento", 321, 654);  
        pessoasFisicas.add(pessoa1);  

        PessoaFisica pessoa2=new PessoaFisica("Tiago Santos", 123, 456);  
        pessoasFisicas.add(pessoa2);      
    }      
}
```

Como mostro para o `Collections.sort` que é para ordenar por nome?

Obs: sei que não precisa implementar a interface Comparator, pois o correto é instanciar e já implementar em tempo de execução, exemplo: `new Comparator<PessoaFisica>();`

mas estou fazendo da forma menos ideal para facilitar meu entendimento.

Comment: Formata esse código ai jovem.

Comment: Essa [reposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114977/varias-ordena%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-arraylist/114981#114981) deve ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*; 

// A class to represent a student. 
public class Student {

    int rollno; 
    String name;
    String address; 

    // Constructor 
    public Student(int rollno, String name, String address) { 
        this.rollno = rollno; 
        this.name = name; 
        this.address = address; 
    } 

    // Used to print student details in main() 
    public String toString() { 
        return this.rollno + " " + this.name + " " + this.address; 
    } 
}
```

```
//Aqui é o que falta para você
class Sortbyroll implements Comparator<Student> { 
    // Used for sorting in ascending order of roll number 
    public int compare(Student a, Student b) { 
        return a.rollno - b.rollno; 
    } 
}
```

```
class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Student> ar = new ArrayList<Student>(); 
        ar.add(new Student(111, "bbbb", "london")); 
        ar.add(new Student(131, "aaaa", "nyc")); 
        ar.add(new Student(121, "cccc", "jaipur")); 

        System.out.println("Sem ordenar"); 
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++){ 
            System.out.println(ar.get(i)); 
        } 

        Collections.sort(ar, new Sortbyroll()); 

        System.out.println("Ordenado por rollno"); 
        for (int i=0; i<ar.size(); i++){ 
            System.out.println(ar.get(i)); 
        }
    } 
}
```

[Fonte](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Você implementou o `Comparator` na `Main`, certo?

Então você deverá passar ao `sort` que a classe `Main` é responsável pela ordenação!

Como você está em um método estático, você deverá instanciar a classe `Main`:

```
  Main main = new Main();

 Collections.sort(pessoasFisicas, main);
```

**Há uma forma de deixar a ordenação por nome como padrão!**

Para isto ao invés de implementar na Classe `Main`,  implemente na Classe `PessoaFisica` a interface [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) :

```
 public class PessoaFisica extends Pessoa implements Comparable<PessoaFisica> {  

    …

    @Override

    public int compareTo(PessoaFisica o) {

        return nome.compareTo(o.nome);

    }  

}
```

Aí você poderá chamar da seguinte forma :

```
Collections.sort(pessoasFisicas);
```

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado. Corrigi.